# Items in Table are gone after a Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

When ever i hide or show the Panel, the items i add (dynamically) to the Table are gone, and another thing is that when i try add new Row to the Table, it won't show it, it's overwriting the same Row, why ??.

Here's the **CodeBehind**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(TextBox3.Text);
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Panel1.Visible == true)
                Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Panel1.Visible == false)
                Panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TableCell tdStudentName = new TableCell();
            tdStudentName.Text = TextBox1.Text;

            TableCell tdStudentCourse = new TableCell();
            tdStudentCourse.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

            TableCell tdStudentGrade = new TableCell();
            tdStudentGrade.Text = TextBox2.Text;

            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tr.Cells.Add(tdStudentName);
            tr.Cells.Add(tdStudentCourse);
            tr.Cells.Add(tdStudentGrade);

            Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the **Html Source**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Student Name:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Course:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add Course" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Grade:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" OnClick="Button4_Click" Text="Add" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" GroupingText="Course Settings" Visible="False">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Add" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">Name</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">Course</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">Grade</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a preview of how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a container which can act as the datasource/itemsource to your table. Then when you press button 4 you can populate that instead and the data will be persistent then until you restart your application. The reason why I have not put this as an answer is because I haven't ever bound anything to a html form before so I don't know whether this can work. Let me know if it works and I can make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you add anything dynamically, then you **must** re-add it on any subsequent post-back.  They will **not** automatically just "be there" on the next post-back.

This requires you to store the fact that the dynamic controls have been created and added, and therefore allows you to detect that on the post-back and add the controls back in again.

It is better (if possible) to add dynamic controls as part of the `init` stage of the [life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as this will mean they will pick up view state information before the `load` stage.

---

**Edit**

In response to the comment by the OP...

> Where do i store these controls ? and where do i add them back ? inside Page_Load ?

You don't store the controls... you store the fact that the controls have been added.

The "easiest" way would be to use the `ViewState`, but that puts you in a [catch-22 situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22)... because the `ViewState` is not available at the `init` stage of the life cycle, which is the preferred place to re-add those controls.

Another option would be to "store the fact" within an `<asp:HiddenField>` which you can check for within the `init` stage.  **However** you would have to get the value directly from the `Request` object, as the field would not have the correct `.Value` at the `init` stage.  You'd do that like...

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   string hdnValue = Request[hdnFieldCtrl.UniqueId];
   // Recreate controls based on the details you need
}
```

Comment: How do you explain the fact that the row and cells i added via design-time are there all the time ?

Comment: Because they're not dynamically added?  They're there in the mark-up?

Comment: Where do i store these controls ? and where do i add them back ? inside Page_Load ?

Comment: You don't store "the controls"... you store the fact they were added.  I will update my answer with some suggestions

Comment: How do you explain the fact that when i add items dynamically to the dropdownlist they dont disappear after a postback ?

Comment: Really?! Because it's not a dynamic control. Sorry, but I don't have time to teach you how to code with ASP.NET

Comment: What do you mean by "you store the fact" ?

Comment: OK, this is the **last** comment I am willing to write... from now on you're on your own.  If you need more help, ask another question.  What I mean by "you store the fact" is that you cannot store the control, it is impossible to store the control, you have to **re-create** the control, and to do that you need some sort of flag, some sort of variable, that allows you (on the post-back) to know that the control needs to be re-created. Good luck